# iterator with fastest runtime, for placeholder

Tags: java, loops

Not sure which syntax to go with, speed is the biggest issue.

I need to increment an int variable from 0-3 after I insert an element, increment by one.

It will be used as a placeholder, to compare inserted elements in a structure, and get them where they need to be.

I just need the placeholder to go from 0-3, and then loop back over to 0 when it is incremented +1 from 3.

The placeholder variable can be stored in the attributes of the class, I don't have a whole lot of restrictions, I just want a simple fast looping iterator.

This is not a homework question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `i = ++i & 3;`, or `i = ++i % 4;`

Comment: Note (more to reader than to EJP): `%` is a clearer and more easily-modifiable operator for this. Any reasonable modern compiler would transform `modulo 4` into `and 3`, there would be no performance difference (not to mention the bottleneck is going to be elsewhere anyways).

Comment: @JasonC: Not necessarily.  In particular, that's not a valid transformation if `i` may be negative.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: You are correct. I incorrectly presumed it would be smart enough to analyze that code; but I just verified that the compiler generates an `irem` for the modulo case and an `iand` for the and, and hotspot does no further optimization (generating `idiv` and `and`, respectively). OpenJDK 7. I hope the OP does not think that `++i` is faster than `i=i+1`, however, or that this is where his bottleneck is. If so, he is going down the wrong path...

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, what's wrong with just using arithmetic?

```
int i = 0;
```

Then on each insert:

```
i = i + 1;
if (i == 3) i = 0;
```

Or, without a branch:

```
i = (i + 1) % 4;
```

Also, this increment (be it branch, modulo, or whatever) is likely going to be the absolute least of your worries as far as bottlenecks go. Implement, profile, find the actual bottleneck and optimize there.

Comment: +1 `i = (i + 1) % 4;` is the most elegant way to do a circular iterator